# How to group elements according to time in streams?

Tags: scala, akka-stream

I have a continuous stream of signals receiving. I want to create a time out for this stream. That is only after 30 seconds the output should be shown. 
How can I give timeout to streams from flows?

Thanks in advance

I tried grouping operations.None worked.

Comment: to be honest i didn't completely get what you want - delay, timeout or grouping. assuming that 'That is only after 30 seconds the output should be shown' is said, i think you are talking about just delay

Comment: I perform an operation on incoming streams. It's like searching the incoming data is correct. So I check for a signal every 30sec. If the signal is not found we give output as Not found. this is the task but i am not able to group according to time duration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To address this, the Akka Streams API has the groupedWithin mechanism to group events, but also emit events within a bounded time-frame, even if the maximum number of events has not been satisfied. This leads to the efficient batching of events, without the introduction of unacceptable latency.

```
Source.tick(0 milliseconds, 10 milliseconds, ())  
.map(_ => Sample(System.currentTimeMillis(), random.nextFloat()))
.groupedWithin(1000, 100 milliseconds)
.map(database.bulkInsert)
.runWith(Sink.ignore)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`delay`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/stream/operators/Source-or-Flow/delay.html) flow for this. eg:

```
Source(...).delay(3.seconds, DelayOverflowStrategy.backpressure).runForeach(...)
```